# Listen to Azure Queue from BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, azure-storage-queues

I've been attempting this for a couple of weeks now. It's a pretty simple concept.

I just want to read messages off of an Azure cloud queue (Not a service buss!) from a local installation of BizTalk Server 2013 R2 and then allow BizTalk to do something with that message on our internal network. I am following this sort of example for creating a port to the Azure Queue:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20211.biztalk-server-2013-connect-to-window-azure-blob-storage.aspx

In my case, this needs to be a receive (it will be receiving queue messages). So, I have a receive location which is a WCF-WebHttp adapter pointed to: https://myappname.queue.core.windows.net/ with operations like:

```
 <Operation Name="Query" Method="Get" Url="/myqueue/messages"/>
 <Operation Name="Remove" Method="Delete" Url="/myqueue/messages"/>
```

That doesn't seem to magically do anything, and i'm not sure how I would initiate a read call to the Azure queue from BizTalk. Do I need to initiate a polling message of some sort? How would I do that with a WCF-WebHttp adapter port?

Maybe the question is: How do I make the orchestration which starts with a WCF-WebHttp receive location do something? Ie. how do I make it poll the queue / what should I be starting the orchestration with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF-WebHttp doesn't have any built in polling mechanism.  You'll have to create or simulate one.

You'll need to do some custom implementation for this at this point.  There are a lot of different options, but I'd probably go with something like one of these.

1. Use the [Scheduled Task Adapter](https://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/) to send the GET requests to the queue endpoint and publish that message to the MessageBox
2. Create a Windows Service or a scheduled job (Powershell maybe?) that does the polling and writes any messages to something (probably either MSMQ or a file location) that BizTalk can consume automatically

Comment: That must be why the only examples I can find are of PUT operations. 


Given this answer and the fact that I keep coming to this conclusion, I am now re-designing infrastructure to use an Azure Service Buss. I think the custom polling mechanism that I would write (likely option 2) would take me as much effort as just switching our infrastructure to an Azure service buss and using a SB-Messaging adapter.